# Attribute mappings in configuring workload identity federation between GCP and GitHub

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, github-actions, openid-connect, workload-identity

I am trying to wrap my head around this new topic, given that there are still too few examples out there and the documentation is rather obscure.

I am trying to reverse engineer [this](https://github.com/outofdevops/ghshr-gcp-wlif) repo.

What I want to understand is the way we inform GCP that OIDC tokens having **specific** attributes (i.e coming from specific orgs/repos/branches etc) are only accepted as valid.

I notice that the iam policy is [defined](https://github.com/outofdevops/ghshr-gcp-wlif/blob/main/terraform-sa/main.tf#L11) as follows:

```
data "google_iam_policy" "wli_user_ghshr" {
  binding {
    role = "roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser"

    members = [
      "principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/projects/${data.google_project.project.number}/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/gh-pool/attribute.full/${var.gh_repo}${var.gh_branch}",
    ]
  }
}
```

then I see that the identity pool provider is also [declared](https://github.com/outofdevops/ghshr-gcp-wlif/blob/main/terraform-wlif/main.tf#L7) like this

```
resource "google_iam_workload_identity_pool_provider" "provider" {
  provider                           = google-beta
  project                            = var.project_id
  workload_identity_pool_id          = google_iam_workload_identity_pool.gh_pool.workload_identity_pool_id
  workload_identity_pool_provider_id = "gh-provider"
  attribute_mapping                  = {
    "google.subject" = "assertion.sub"
    "attribute.full" = "assertion.repository+assertion.ref"
  }
  oidc {
    allowed_audiences = ["google-wlif"]
    issuer_uri        = "https://token.actions.githubusercontent.com"
  }
}
```

My question is the following:

does this line in the iam policy declaration

```
"principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/projects/${data.google_project.project.number}/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/gh-pool/attribute.full/${var.gh_repo}${var.gh_branch}",
```

must be aligned with the attribute mapping in the identity pool provider's `attribute_mapping` field, i.e

```
  attribute_mapping                  = {
    "google.subject" = "assertion.sub"
    "attribute.full" = "assertion.repository+assertion.ref"
  }
```

i.e. is the `attribute.full`

```
"attribute.full" = "assertion.repository+assertion.ref"
```

is reflected in the last part of the `principalSet` of the iam policy as follows:

```
attribute.full/${var.gh_repo}${var.gh_branch}"
```

?

If so, in the `attribute_mapping` `google.subject` field, what's the role of `assertion.sub`? Does the value of the `assertion.sub` has to be something **specific**?

If so, where is this stated / reflected?

Answer (score 1):

In the specific example from the repo only `attribute.full` is used. So you could just use:

```
  attribute_mapping                  = {
    "google.subject" = "assertion.repository+assertion.ref"
  }
```

and change the IAM policy for the service account to to grant Workload Identity User permissions to the identity:

```
principal://iam.googleapis.com/projects/${data.google_project.project.number}/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/gh-pool/subject/${var.gh_repo}${var.gh_branch}
```

Hope this helps, I have also mode a second video to explain this in greater details: https://youtu.be/fa9jHNaG4SA